# divide the column value if match the case condition in query

Tags: php, mysql, case

I am trying to get the amount accordion to yearly or monthly status.

Here is the column Y = Yearly and M = Monthly.

```
period_stats | Amount
Y            | 12070.00
M            | 2580.00
```

I want to query the amount according to amount that if `period_stats` is `Y` then the amount should be get divided by 12, and if `period_stats` is `M` then want to get direct amount without division.

> I am not a pro in sql, so after some searching i found that i can do
>   it with using `case` in sql but i didn't get how to use it.

I have tried this way. Please Correct me if i am using it wrongly.

```
select period_stats, CASE period_stats
WHEN 'Y' THEN (amount / 12) as amount_monthly
ELSE amount END as 'amount_monthly' FROM tbale where id = 1;
```

If anyone know any other technique then it will be appreciated and i like to know that also.

---

#### The conclusion:

Correct query to get that desired result. (by using the Sebastian Brosch answer)

```
SELECT 
period_stats, 
ROUND(CASE WHEN (period_stats = 'Y') THEN (amount / 12) ELSE amount END, 2) 
AS 'amount_monthly'
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Result:

```
amount_monthly
1005
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT 
    period_stats, 
    CASE WHEN (period_stats = 'Y') THEN (amount / 12) ELSE amount END AS 'amount_monthly'
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1;
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1521ad/2/0

The query above is using the following syntax:

```
CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END
```

> **source:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

---

To show only two decimal places you can use [`TRUNCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) (without rounding) or [`ROUND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) (with rounding).

**The solution using `TRUNCATE`:**

```
SELECT 
    period_stats, 
    TRUNCATE(CASE WHEN (period_stats = 'Y') THEN (amount / 12) ELSE amount END, 2) AS 'amount_monthly'
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1;
```

**The solution using `ROUND`:**

```
SELECT 
    period_stats, 
    ROUND(CASE WHEN (period_stats = 'Y') THEN (amount / 12) ELSE amount END, 2) AS 'amount_monthly'
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: just one query that the result is something like `12313.00000` so how do i get it like `12313.00` or `12313`. @SebastianBrosch

Comment: Your help is really appreciated. and Thanks for sharing the syntax, again  Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it.

```
        select period_stats , 
        IF(`period_stats`='Y',`Amount`/12 , `Amount`) AS amount_monthly
        FROM table where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Vijtiwari your query is also working fine but using if condition in sql query is a good practice?

Comment: you can CAST the column like below if you want to get the integer value 
`CAST(columnName AS INT)`

Answer (score 2):

You can write your query like this:

```
SELECT period_stats, 
    CASE period_stats 
    WHEN "Y" THEN Amount/12 
    ELSE Amount 
    END AS 'amount_monthly' 
FROM tbale where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks your query is also working. up for that. thanks sir.